# Why does git prevent merging binary files?

Tags: git, binaryfiles, gitattributes

I was browsing yarn's [berry](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/) repository and stumbled upon this setting in their `.gitattributes` file:

```sh
# Mark .pnp.js as binary to prevent git from trying to merge it
/.pnp.js                binary linguist-generated
```

Why does git, by default, prevent binary files from being merged automatically? Is it because most editors would fare poorly at editing the contents of such files?

Comment: It's not so much *prevent* as *unable to do*. Git has no idea how to merge binary files. If Git judges a file to be binary on its own, it doesn't even try. If it judges the file to be text, it tries—and then it may or may not *think* it succeeds. If you put in your own declaration, that the file *is* or *is not* text, you can adjust Git's attempts, but not its actual degree of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First because it is meaningless. How do you merge two executable files? What would be the result? Will it be also executable?

Second because git is technically oriented towards working with lines. It merges files line-by-line (well, blocks of lines). And binary files don't have lines.

Comment: To go further in examples, images are binaries as well. If the original image is a monkey, your friend turned it into a giraffe and you decided to draw a dog on your side, are you expecting to automagically see a "monrag" as a result of the merge ?